# Java KeyListener: KeyTyped Backspace, Esc as input

Tags: java, keylistener, backspace

Inside the `KeyTyped` method, how do I tell if <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> is being pressed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/8/index.htm

When `arg0.getKeyChar()` is cast to an int: `(int)arg0.getKeyChar()`, The backspace key comes up with the value 8, and the Esc key comes up with the value 27.

Answer (score 26):

Assuming you have attached the KeyListener properly and have implemented the methods required for that KeyListener, to detect specific key-presses simply add the following code:

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) 
{
    int keyCode = ke.getKeyCode();
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
    {  
        //code to execute if backspace is pressed
    }
     
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
    {
        //code to execute if escape is pressed
    }
}
```

The KeyEvent class javadocs can be found at the following link: [KeyEvent javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html).
There you can find a list of all of the Java virtual keycodes used to detect keyboard input when implementing Java KeyListeners and KeyEvents. More information about KeyListeners can be found here: [How to Write a Key Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).  To use the keyTyped method as asked, see [gangqinlaohu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15693905/1518042).

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work. Inside the keyTyped() method, ke.getKeyCode() has no value. And sometimes, it is useful to be able to tell if these characters are typed inside keyTyped(). One other way of doing it is to make a boolean that is flagged in the keyReleased() method.

Comment: @gangqinlaohu, I see that now looking more closely at the KeyEvent javadocs. In the keyTyped method, ke.getKeyCode() will always return a keycode of VK_UNDEFINED. I have only ever used keyPressed and keyReleased myself, so I've never encountered that issue before. Thank you for pointing that out. I have corrected my answer to reflect how I would approach keyboard input, and linked to your solution, which was accepted as the solution.

Comment: keyTyped is generally useful for typed characters. Getting the characters from keyReleased tends to be more difficult.

Answer (score 5):

**Only for java 7 / jdk1.7 and above:** In case you are checking against `event.getKeyCode()`, try the `event.getExtendedKeyCode()` method. In case of the back-space it will return the proper code (in this case, 8) instead of a plain 0. That way there is no need to check against `\b`:

```
if (e.getExtendedKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
    System.out.println("Backspace pressed");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I understand this is a very old subject, but I wanted to add an answer that I found helped me greatly with the same issue.

I'm making a chat input for a Java program, and its better to use KeyTyped as opposed to pressed and released (as it excluded the need to filter most characters). Anyways I wanted to make backspace delete characters, but the .getKeyCode() always returned 0 as per the documentation. However, you can use .getKeyChar() to return the character (probably will appear as a square box), and the escape character '\b' to do a comparison.

```
if(tmp.getKeyChar().equals('\b')) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `e.getExtendedKeyCode()` in `keyTyped` and it returns non-zero values that appear correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code, I hope it will work for you.

```
@FXML
public void keyPresses(KeyEvent ke) 
{
    if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE)) {
        System.out.println("It Works Backspace pressed..!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is for JavaFX, whereas the question was for Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to use the KeyPressed event for keys other than letters/numbers, as when you're typing the Backspace or Enter keys, nothing is actually being typed per say. Here's what I did that worked (make sure KeyCode and KeyEvent are imported from javafx.scene.input)!

```
MyTextArea.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE)){
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
    }
});
```

Let me know if this worked for you :)