# Capture changes in console

Tags: java, console

I'd like to catch if user enters/deletes character from console before clicking 'enter'. Is simply way to do that in Java?
Thank you for any tips

Comment: No, you cannot. The terminal emulator decides when to submit data to the program.

Comment: No, there is no easy way. The only way to do is to use a (J)TextArea, create TextAreaInput/OutputStreams, and use System.setOut/In/Err

Comment: Not sure but I think KeyListeners can be used? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693904/java-keylistener-keytyped-backspace-esc-as-input